# How to understand rootScope?

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning angularjs. When I learn scope, I see rootScope. But I don't really  understand what it is.

For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://cdn.static.runoob.com/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h1>Family Name {{lastname}} Members:</h1>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names">{{x}} {{lastname}}</li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
    $rootScope.lastname = "Refsnes";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But I don't understand what's the difference between the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://cdn.static.runoob.com/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h1>Family Name {{lastname}} Members:</h1>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names">{{x}} {{lastname}}</li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
    $scope.lastname = "Refsnes";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So if there is no difference between scope and rootScope, why do we need to use rootScope?

I hope someone can give me a simple example so that I can understand rootScope easily.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add to @Yaser answer. I will use google chrome console to explain the `$rootScope` hierarchy which is inherited by all the scopes in the entire web page.

Step 1: Open chrome web developer tool and select the div with `ng-app = "myApp"`

Step 2: Goto  chrome web developer tool's console and type `angular.element($0).scope()`, this will fetch you an object containing `$rootScope` details.

Here you will find a property **lastname: "Refsnes"**

[image]

Step 3: Goto Elements tab and select one of the `<li>`

Step 4: Type `angular.element($0).scope()` in the console, this will fetch you and object containing selected scope's details

Expand the parent property and you will find rootScope's property **lastname: "Refsnes"**

[image]

This should explain how `$rootScope` is inherited by all other scopes on the web page

Answer (score 1):

Every application has a `single` root scope. All other scopes are descendant scopes of the root scope. Scopes provide separation between the model and the view, via a mechanism for watching the model for changes. They also provide event emission/broadcast and subscription facility.

More info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope).

However a very simple explanation is consider rootScope and the original parent of all child scopes. If you imagine a hierarchy the rootScope is at the top.

I case of your example there is no rootScope involved, it is just a perent scope.
So you have a `lastname` in your parent scope, and since `ng-repeat` creates a child scope, everyone of them has a `lastname` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The $rootScope is the top-most scope. An app can have only one $rootScope which will be shared among all the components of an app. Hence it acts like a global variable. All other $scopes are children of the $rootScope.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope','$rootScope', function ($scope,$rootScope) {
  
   $rootScope.name = "Rahul";
}]);

app.controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope','$rootScope', function ($scope,$rootScope) {
   $scope.name = $rootScope.name;
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div>
  
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">  
    <span>{{name}}</span> - controller -1
</div>
<hr>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    <span>{{name}}</span> - controller -2      
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

var app = angular.module('myApp',[]) [enter image description here][1] //Here rootScope is created only one time

Check structure from the link: - https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzBj3.png

Here is a simple use of rootScope as passing data from one controlleer to another